# GCC Compiler Optimizations, can't link with a main executable file '_' for architecture x86_64

Tags: c, gcc

`*Antonio10ms$ gcc pi.c -o1 pi

ld: can't link with a main executable file 'pi' for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I need help please to make an optimization to my .cpp

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confusing the optimization argument with the output/target argument.

I think what you want is

```
gcc pi.c -o1 -o pi
```

where
"-o1" means "optimization level 1"
and
"-o pi" means "output to an executable named pi"