# gcc options case sensitivity, passing `-on` instead of `-On`

Tags: gcc

I just came across this answer [GCC Compiler Optimizations, can't link with a main executable file '_' for architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105610/gcc-compiler-optimizations-cant-link-with-a-main-executable-file-for-archi/46105687#46105687) and it made me wonder, is gcc really case sensitive and if yes, what is `-on` actually? I always used `-On` to indicate the level of optimization desired. `-on` does not make any sense to me. However, I tried a little program with `-o3` and gcc swallowed it happily. I was unable to find what `-on` could stand for. In my little test this key has not affected the output in any way, as far as I recognize, while `-O3` resulted in smaller executable.

I presumed, that gcc must be case sensitive everywhere - be it Windows or Unix-like OS with case-sensitive FS, at least wrt to command options. And I expected gcc to bail out with error message `unrecognized option '-o3'` when fed it with `-o3`, however, it did not.

`gcc --version` is

```
gcc (Gentoo 5.4.0-r3 p1.3, pie-0.6.5) 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

`arch` output:

```
x86_64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-o` option sets the output file to write to, so compiling with `-o3` will cause the compiler to generate an object or executable file called `3`

Comment: Erm, lol, that's true. I had to inspect `ls` output more carefully. There's actually a file `3` and `file` says `./3: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped, with debug_info`. Thank you.

Comment: I always put a space between `-o` and an output file name, so it's kind of surprise to me, tbh. Besides `man gcc` follows the same convention and does not say much about the form `-ofilename`.